# In Swift: the example below why must I place (let one) next to .Success for the code to work?

Tags: string, swift, enums, switch-statement, case

In the example below why must I place `(let one)` next to `.Success` for the code to work? Why is it not `(let = one)` or just `(one)`? I am trying to understand the syntax.

```
enum Status {
    case Success(String)
    case Failure(String)
}
let downloadStatus = Status.Failure("Network connection unavailable")

switch downloadStatus {
case .Success(let one):
    println(one)
case .Failure(let two):
    println(two)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known as *value binding*.  The value contained in the `enum` value is temporarily bound to the variable in the `case`.  If you use `let` the value will be bound to a constant and if you use `var` it will be bound to a variable.

```
let downloadStatus = Status.Failure("Network connection unavailable")

switch downloadStatus {
case .Success(let one):
    println(one)
case .Failure(var two):
    two += "!!!"  // two is a var, so I can modify it
    println(two)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to understand the syntax

There is nothing to understand. That simply *is* the syntax for extracting the associated value from an enum case. It's like the masks when you play Calvinball - no one is allowed to question them.

Now, you might object that this syntax is kind of clumsy and annoying. You have to go through the rigmarole of a switch statement just to pull out the associated value?!? That is a perfectly valid complaint, people have been making it since Swift was unveiled in June 2014, and the folks at Apple know that it's kind of weird and may change it in future. But for now, that's the syntax, and that's all there is to know about it.